# Avoid mobile version of YouTube

Tags: youtube

For some reason, either Vodafone UK or YouTube think they are smarter than my own desires and are constantly redirecting my phone to use the mobile version of YouTube.

This would be fine, except whenever I click a direct video link from somewhere else on the web (even from Google results that I got using the phone itself) I get kicked back to the mobile version's index page, with no assistance to find what I was originally trying to watch!

This even happens when I click the "Desktop" link on either my phone or Chrome through wireless hotspotting, and it's extremely irritating - especially through Chrome as that should be the user agent being "detected", if anything - device neutrality anyone?!

If anyone knows at what level this is happening and/or how to stop it, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is 2018 and I'm struggling with the same issues...

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the default action for youtube links to the browser?  You may need to reset it (Settings --> Applications --> Manage Applications --> app -->  "Clear Defaults") so that you can choose the Youtube app when wanting to view a Youtube video.

Comment: Well I don't want to use the YouTube app for YouTube videos, I'm quite happy with the mobile version of the site, except when I'm accessing it via my laptop using my phone as a wireless hotspot, in which case I should be given the proper version of the site.

Also it shouldn't have anything to do with the link actions as I'm not clicking the link on my phone, it's simply passing through my phone.

Comment: The YouTube app is great, I recommend that you just give it a try.  Being satisfied with something is no reason to avoid trying something else.  As for using your phone as a hotspot, it sounds like your carrier is trying to force you into the mobile site.  Either that or Google knows your IP address is from Vodaphone.  Have you tried seeing what happens when you go to YouTube through a proxy site, e.g. facebookproxy.co.uk?

Answer (score 0):

If you download Dolphin browser, add the Desktop toggles add-on you should be able to view it as a normal webpage (make sure to enable desktop toggles and delete the "m." in the url)

That would solve the problem on your phone, as regards using it as a hotspot, i assume you tried deleting the "m." in the url? I think its the browser version youtube looks at when deciding what version of the site to serve so i dont know why it would serve the mobile version on your pc