# See YouTube videos in Anaglyph mode

Tags: youtube, stereo-video

How to see a YouTube video in [Anaglyph mode](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1683835&guide=1680728&page=guide.cs) from a non-3D Android device? I am not able to enable Anaglyph mode from the YouTube application.

Comment: If you find a way to get to the desktop version of YouTube, you may be able to do this by using the flash video player. But [that seems to be not all that easy](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4088/avoid-mobile-version-of-youtube).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download [Dolphin browse](http://dolphin-browser.com/)r, add the [Desktop toggles](http://dolphin-browser.com/add-ons/tools/desktop-toggles/) add-on you should be able to view it as a normal webpage (make sure to enable desktop toggles and delete the "m." in the url)